# Change Current Location label text

Tags: iphone, geolocation, location

I had already googled for an answer, but nothing happens...
I need to change the text of the blue point that show the current location.
When you geolocalize your position, the iPhone shows you a blue point with your position, if you tap it, its show you a text that says "Current Location". I need to change that text with something like... "Here you are", by example.

I really appreciate your answer, thx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That blue dot is an instance of MKUserLocation. You can access it by calling the map view's `userLocation` property. You can then change it's title and subtitle properties.

[Here's the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKUserLocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html).